# How to change port number for apache in WAMP

Tags: apache, wamp

I am new to WAMP server and installed it on my system but after installing it when I check it by going to localhost url like this  `http://localhost/` in the browser it is not working.  I am getting a **404 error and blank page**.

This is because my 80 port which default in `Wamp server` is being used by IIS server. So please let me know how to change port number in Wamp server and solved this problem.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Click on the WAMP server icon and from the menu under *Config Files* select 
`httpd.conf`. A long text file will open up in notepad. In this file scroll 
down to the line that reads `Port 80` and change this to read `Port 8080`, 
Save the file and close notepad. Once again click on the wamp server icon and
 select restart all services. One more change needs to be made before we are 
done. In Windows Explorer find the location where WAMP server was installed 
which is by Default `C:\Wamp`.

---

**Update :** On a newer version of WAMP, click the *WAMP server icon* **>** *Apache* **>** `httpd.conf`, then change the line `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080` or any port you want.

**Update：** On 3.1.6 version of WAMP ， right click on the  *wamp server icon* in the taskbar ，select "tools"-> "Port  used by Apache:80" -> "use  a port other than 80", an  input box  will pop  up , input  a  new  port in it，click confirm button , then restart  wamp .

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Listen 8080` rather than `Port 8080`?

Comment: may be your other application is using that 80 port , so u just need to  change the port and it will work for you.

Comment: Related to this - I also had to change the port to different one, but then the links from the WampServer system tray monitor didn't work. They kept pointing to plain "localhost/". 
To change it, I tried editing the c:\wamp\wampmanager.ini, but that one seemed to get overwritten with defaults each time the wampserver is restarted. Anyway, after adding the new port number in the c:\wamp\wampmanager.tpl (template, I guess), all started working after next wamp restart. Just thought I should share. :)

Comment: Also change the url links in wamp\wampmanager.tpl to get the shortcuts from the task bar working

Comment: Wikipedia lists port numbers and common uses. States 80, 8080, and 8008 as common alternative http ports. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Answer (score 106):

Just go to httpd.conf file, for ex. under WAMP environment its situated at:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf
```

go to line no. 46 and edit `Listen 80` to your requirement for ex.

```
Listen 8383
```

newer versions of WAMP uses these 2 lines:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8383  
Listen [::0]:8383
```

Next go to line no. 171 and edit `ServerName localhost:80` to your requirement for ex.

```
ServerName localhost:8383
```

`Restart Apache` and its done !!

Now, you can access with your URL:

```
http://localhost:8383 or http://192.168.1.1:8383
```

Hope it helps to people looking for solution here.

Comment: If you use VirtualHosts then you also need to update them to use <VirtualHost *:8383> instead of <VirtualHost *:80>

Answer (score 35):

From the **wampserver 3.x** onwards, **changing the listening port number of Apache** does not require any particular Apache skills (http.conf, virtualhost,...), you just have to *click button* - assuming you're running Windows OS! :

1. In the tray, right click green/running **WAMP** icon
2. Select menu **Tools**
3. In the section *Port used by Apache: xx*, click **Use a port other than 80** *(i.e. default port configuration)*
4. Enter the desired port number in the popup window - *usually 8080 as alternative Web port*

NB: For alternative port: check official [IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)

Answer (score 12):

Change port number for Xampp
Go to the file 
C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

Change 80 to 82

as

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:82
Listen 82
```

now your url will be

```
http://localhost:82
```

Comment: I changed and it works! But can I hide the port from the url? It should use port 82 but should not display in url. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

In lieu of changing the port, I reclaimed port 80 as being used by IIS.

So I went to services, and stopped the following:

1. World Wide Web Publishing Services.
2. Web Management Service
3. Web Deployment Agent Service.

set them to manual so that it will not start on dev environment restart.

Comment: I like this approach rather than changing the port. On Windows 10, all I had to disable was World Wide Web Publishing Services

Answer (score 6):

In addition of the modification of the file `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf\httpd.conf`.
To get the url shortcuts working, edit the file `C:\wamp64\wampmanager.conf` and change the port:

```
[apache]
apachePortUsed = "8080"
```

Then exit and relaunch wamp.

Comment: ```[apache]
apachePortUsed = "8080"``` how if I want to add more than one port?

Answer (score 4):

You could try changing Apache server to listen to some other port other than port 80.

Click on yellow WAMP icon in your taskbar
Choose Apache -> httpd.conf
Inside find these two lines of code:

Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
and change them to something like this (they are not one next to the other):

Listen 8080
ServerName localhost:8080

Answer (score 2):

Click on the WAMP server icon and from the menu under Config Files select
httpd.conf. A long text file will open up in notepad. In this file scroll
down to the line that reads Port 80 and change this to read Port 8080,
Save the file and close notepad. Once again click on the wamp server icon and
select restart all services. One more change needs to be made before we are
done. In Windows Explorer find the location where WAMP server was installed
which is by Default C:\Wamp.