# Wamp server icon will not turn green

Tags: wamp, appserver

I read many similar questions about it but the solutions are not working for me.

The icon says WAMP Server online but it stays orange.

when I test port 80 under Apache/services/Test port 80 it says that port 80 is actually used by: Server: Apache/2.2.8   PHP/5.2.6

Shouldn't that be a good thing? As there are no other programs using port 80, despite that when I type local host I get a weird page instead of the normal one, it has pink bars

The AppServ Open Project - 2.5.10 for Windows

```
phpMyAdmin Database Manager Version 2.10.3
PHP Information Version 5.2.6

About AppServ Version 2.5.10 for Windows
AppServ is a merging open source software installer package for Windows includes :

    Apache Web Server Version 2.2.8
    PHP Script Language Version 5.2.6
    MySQL Database Version 5.0.51b
    phpMyAdmin Database Manager Version 2.10.3

ChangeLog
README
AUTHORS
COPYING
Official Site : http://www.AppServNetwork.com
Hosting support by : http://www.AppServHosting.com

    Change Language :  

Easy way to build Webserver, Database Server with AppServ :-)
```

---

I really need to start working in this project but this is preventing me from even starting.

Comment: Why don't you uninstall App Serv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you really know what you are doing you should only have ONE Apache on your system.

Basically WAMPServer and APPServ are the same thing, that is they are installers for the WAMP Stack i.e. Apache, MySQL and PHP.

You only need one of them so uninstall the other, of course remember to backup anything you may want to move over to the other before you uninstall one of them.

Comment: My god I thought it was the same thing, I dont even remember isntalling APP server but its working now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

I have solution...

1. Click WampServer icon in tray icons -> Apache -> Service -> Install service
   (same for mysql -> Service -> Install service )
2. Then, Apache -> Service -> Start service (same for MySql -> Service -> Start service)

done! Enjoy :-)

Comment: This answer is also useful for those who just copy paste (like in new windows installation) the wamp folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Skype, stop it since it uses port80 which is needed by WAMP

You can also switch the port needed for Wamp. 
Follow this article 
[How to change port number for apache in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp)

Answer (score 0):

Check if MySQL is running or not

Click on Wamp icon in icon tray then

MySQL->Service

if Start/Resume Service is visible and clickable it means your MySQL service is not running that's why it is giving you problem.

It's possible that you have installed some other application that installed and running MySQL - so already having one MySQL running is what conflicting with wamp's MySQL.

How to stop other MySQL from running?

Simply go to My Computer and search for file name "my.ini" (without quotes)

There should be at-least two my.ini files on your computer delete all other my.ini except the one in wamp directory

Restart your computer and start the wamp server it should solve your problem

Comment: thank you, the previosu answer worked but at the time I did not know how to properly mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: No problem - it may help someone having the same problem

Comment: @Muhammad i got the problem your way but the solution is not working as I have only 1 my.ini on my system. Is there any other way?

Comment: @asachanfbd the solution above is when you have two different mysql  running - If you have only one then it may have something to do with your database - Try this: go to `wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data` and move `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` files to somewhere else and restart wamp - let me know if it doesn't solve problem

Comment: @Muhammad thanks for the help, but this solution didn't worked either. After looking at log file I found that one of my table is corrupt. Weird thing was only change in my system was RAM from 4GB to 2GB. After table recovery and working fine for 1 Day the problem appeared again and this time again the only change was RAM from 2GB to 4GB. After that it is still working fine. I could not understand what was the relation between RAM and db table.

Answer (score 0):

As of WampServer 2.5 (64bit), these are the things I had to do to get it to go green:

1. In your `my.ini`

   - Change `[wampmysqld]` to `[wampmysqld64]`. Now when you start/stop wamp you should get information in your mysql log file (and errors if you have any).
   - I uncommented all the innodb lines under where it says `Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables` (except for innodb_log_arch_dir and innodb_additional_mem_pool_size).
   - Make sure the `innodb_data_home_dir` is set properly, like `innodb_data_home_dir = C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data/`. Do the same for `innodb_log_group_home_dir`.
   - Change the locale line to read `lc-messages=en_US` for English.
   - You can confirm mysql is up and running with Wamp Icon > Mysql > Service (Start/Resume service should be greyed out)
2. Install and start apache:

   - Wamp Icon > Apache > Service > Install Service.
   - Wamp Icon > Apache > Service > Start.  (you can click on "test port 80" to see if something was blocking it like others have mentioned, such as skype, sql reports, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

During the starting of WAMP server, the Apache service should be started as well. In case, it doesn’t start; WAMP server won’t perform as it should be.

To fix this issue, navigate to the WAMP server icon in the system tray > Apache > Service administration ‘wampapache64’ > Install Service.

it will open the Command Prompt on your screen. After closing the Command Prompt, go to the same path and click on Start/Resume Service.

The WAMP server icon should turn to green right away.

In case you can have all these but still, the icon is displaying orange color, you need to click on Restart Service button.