# Possibly Port Error

Tags: apache, tomcat

I already installed Tomcat server while developing my java web app. But I also needed to get access to my database using PHPMyAdmin and install MySQL as well, so I downloaded XAMPP. I cannot disable apache server since I already have Tomcat. Now my struggle is, I cannot open

"localhost:8080" which was my original port. It's now replaced with simply "localhost".

Can you help me fix this error? THANK YOU :D

Comment: 'It is now replaced' where?

Comment: you can change apache server port http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you now have:

- Tomcat serving traffic on port 8080, as it always has (at `http://localhost:8080`)
- Apache/XAMPP serving traffic on port 80 (at `http://localhost`, obviously with the port missing since 80 is the default http port)

Assuming that's the case, you don't have a problem.  Serving http traffic from different ports on the same host is not an issue.