# Wampserver/ apache not working

Tags: apache

my wampserver is showing an yellow icon.. when i click on install service it shows an error like:

"your port is actually used by:

Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

cannot install the apache service.please stop the application and try again"
plz help 
thnx

Answer (score 1):

Port 80 is already used by IIS (*Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0*).  Stop IIS first or use another port for WAMP.  To use another port have a look at this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Microsoft SQL server too, there's probably a SQL Reporting Service running on port 80, which is blocking your Apache. Just stop or disable it.

Name: ReportServer

Description: SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)