# Why do I need to use 'localhost:8080' instead of just 'localhost' to connect to my server WAMP?

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, wamp

I am currently using WAMP server on my Windows XP SP2 system. I just want to know why do I need to use `localhost:8080` instead of just `localhost` to connect to my server-WAMP? I'm not that interested in this `:8080` stuff.

So if you guys know why this happens, or how to exclude `:8080` from the address, just help me through. Thank you very much by the way. Have a nice day.

**Notice:** Please don't tell me to switch to XAMPP. I know it works well.

Comment: what happens when you type localhost only,also i thought the default port is 80

Comment: If Apache wont run on port 80 then something else has captured port 80 before you can start Apache. The best solution is to find out what is using port 80 and either uninstall it if you are not using it, or reconfigure whatever is using port 80 to use another port. If you cannot do this, then you are stuck with using an alternat port and having to enter it on every url manually. The next version of WAMPServer will have a new feature to automate the use of an additional port number but I am not sure when that is slated for release.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your server is listening on port 8080, and not on port 80 which is the default (so when you type localhost you mean localhost:80).

So, you need to change your configuration to make WAMP listening on port 80. You find here how to do this: [How to change port number for apache in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. Actually, if they are saying about 'Apache > httpd.config', then it is already Listen 8080 here and still I have to use localhost:8080 instead of just localhost.

Comment: But if you want WAMP to listen on port 80 you have to put Listen 80, not Listen 8080... Then save and reboot the WAMP service.

Comment: It won't help(keeps offline) if I do so.

Comment: Another program is likely to listen on port 80. You could try to run on your command `netstat -aon`. Then look a the PID in the line you see LISTENING on 0.0.0.0:80. That is the process listening on port 80. Then you need to stop this process and restart WAMP with Listen 80 in the conf file and it will work.