# Can't connect to phpMyAdmin or localhost

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Hi I've recently downloaded wamp server to help me with my website. My problem is that when I click on phpmyadmin I get an error message *"HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."*

Also when I click on my localhost  i get this page which I don't think is correct[image: f]

Finally to see my webpages I have to write http://localhost:8888/. If I placed the 8888 in front of of phpMyAdmin then I can see the phpmyadmin but its not synced with my mysql database and tables that I created, it's just a plain phpmyadmin. I don't know what to change or where to start to change things to get it to work properly so that I can see my tables and databases I created in mysql in PHPmyadmin.

In my httpd.conf the servername is *ServerName localhost:81*and the listen *listen 81*

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_4ttrrbno8)

Comment: I guess you might want to see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp

Comment: Do you have IIS(internet information service) installed on your computer?

Comment: You could have stopped the iss by using he comand "net stop was /y" in cmd with administrator rights.. Or you can permanently disable iss using the windows features

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. Yes I do have IIS  installed on my computer

Comment: Should change anything to the IIS?

Comment: It says Requested URL    http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin/ but Im sure Ive changed the localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not a problem to run IIS on your computer, you can even server phpMyAdmin from it if you have PHP properly configured. It sounds like you're running another webserver alongside IIS (I'm perceiving this based on the numerous ports you're using, you've referenced port 80, 81, 8080, and 8888), which also is fine (again, as long as you have them properly configured so as to not conflict). You can have one listen on port 80 and the other on 8080, for instance, so there's no conflict of ports.

You have to know which server is using which ports, and which server you're expecting to use phpMyAdmin from. If IIS isn't using the PHP interpreter and isn't configured to serve phpMyAdmin, then using the IIS port will give you the 404 error -- which appears to be the initial cause of your screenshot here.

You said that if you do use port 8888 you can use phpMyAdmin, but without access to the databases you expect to see. This is a good start and means one of two things happen -- either you're logged in as a user who doesn't have privileges to see those databases (perhaps the anonymous user) or you've also got two MySQL instances running on your machine with their own datadir (well, I couldn't even imagine what data corruption would occur if they shared the same datadir). Do you see any databases at all? Can you create a new database?

Can you connect at the command line client and see your databases? From the command line client use the `STATUS;` command to see the user and host you're connected as, then compare those to what's shown on the main page of phpMyAdmin. Note that hosts matter, `%` is not the same as `localhost`.