# wamp blank page before and after changing port

Tags: apache, wamp

- wamp blank page at http://localhost at default port 80.

  - Wamp icon green,
  - "all services runnig".
  - `wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80` says port 80 is used
  - `netstat -ao` showing no process at local port 80, only PID matching httpd.exe
- changing port to 8383 in httpd.conf as described in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713963/3190476 and visit http://localhost:8383/ also result in blank page.

  - `netstat -ao` showing only httpd.exe using port 8383

Comment: What do you expect to see (what is the index file suppose to show)?
What does the browser console say (any errors)?

Answer (score 0):

WAMP reinstallation solved the problem.