# WAMP Apache won't start Port 80 is being used

Tags: apache, service, wamp, wampserver

Just installed WAMP on a relatively new install of windows 10. Apache doesn't start.

### I've tried:

### WAMP icon -> Apache -> Service Administration -> Install Apache

**Error:**

```
`Your port 80 is actually used by :
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0`
```

### Stopping services/Uninstalling programs:

Unfortunatly most of the services/applications that typically use and block port 80 aren't installed on my computer.

Some of these are:

- SQL Server Reporting Service
- Web Deployment Agent Service
- Skype
- IIS

### Checked Windows features

Went into Enable/Disable windows features and made sure IIS is disabled

### netstat -o

Gives inconsistant results. Sometimes PID 0 is listening to port 80, other times, PID 4.

**Start up error:**

On start up I get the error: The application was unable to start correctly (0x0000142). Click OK to close the application.

---

I'm lost. I feel like I've tried everything and nothing works.
What am I missing?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You may want to just change the port that Apache is running on - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp

Comment: I really don't want to do that because it messes with virtual hosts.