# PHP file not opening with html head tag

Tags: php, html, web, server, xampp

When I open this php file, it does not load:

```
<?php 
    echo "I am awesome";
?>
<html>
<head> </head>
</html>
```

Error screenshot

[image]
However, if I remove the `<head>` tag, code works fine.

I've used both Xampp and Wamp servers on Windows PC, tried changing ports but the issue still persists.

**Solved:** Using http://127.0.0.1/test.php instead of http://localhost/test.php fixed the problem for me and code executed successfully.

Comment: what name you have saved your file?

Comment: Seems to be working for me

Comment: When starting, look into the **Windows Event Log** to see the error why the server can't start up.

Comment: I've saved the file with name test.php. The server is starting properly, I can even view other php files in my browser which do not have <head> tag.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that your `Apache` is started successfully (either in `xampp` or `wamp`).

If `Apache` is not started. Try closing applications that might use port 80 of your computer.

OR

Change server port in `xampp` or `wamp` configurations.
Here is guides to perform that:

[Change port in xampp](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/)

[Change port in wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp)

Comment: Apache starts successfully. Browser even runs the file without <head>.

Comment: @Vikram <head> is HTML tag and is totally unrelated to apache. Html does not need any web server to get executed. 
Make sure you don't have any proxy or VPN opened.

Comment: @Vikram What is the url that you enter into your browser ?

Comment: @Vikram Try localhost and see if it lists your directories and apache functions normally

Comment: localhost is not working as well but 127.0.0.1 opens the dashboard. And when I tried http://127.0.0.1/test.php, it worked! I'm still trying to understand what happened

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Apache server is not working properly, You config again and restart your apache server. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNW6C.png)

Comment: Apache server seems to work fine. Yet I've tried changing ports multiple times. Also, code works in other computers but not mine.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have saved it as html. Change it to php.